# Array containing same data from table instead of different data with ToArray()

Tags: c#, linq

I am stuck on a crazy issue.

I have a list of strings

```
string[] mat = { "AAD","AAV"};
```

I am creating an array of objects

```
Car[] cars = new Car[] {};
```

I query the table Car where RefNumber is in mat array

```
Cars = (from lc in _context.Car.Where(c => mat.Contains(c.RefNumber)) select lc).ToArray();
```

The query runs as expected (The output shows the correct sql :

`select * from Car c where c.RefNumber in ('AAD','AAV')`

However the array contains 2 lines but of the same data ! AAD. I never see AAV populated inside the array. What's wrong? I've tried lists too. I'm stuck.

Comment: why do you create Cars as Array of objects ? This is useless.
And to tell you why your query results are as they are, we need to see your data.
If there are no entries with AAV in your _context.Car, it will never appear in the result. But if there are, your query looks good, they should appear.

Comment: @Holger Yes, there are entries with AAV and the query works. How to translate the results of that query correctly to that array is where I'm stuck. I want Car[0] to contain data of "AAD" and Car[1] to contain data of "AAV".

Comment: How can the query work, but you don't like the results ? That does not make sense.
Converting to the array, is the "ToArray()" and there is nothing to do wrong.
How do you get the idea you have Car[0] and Car[1] ? Your Array length will be 100 oder 1000, if you have many cars, in your _context.Car table.
You are filtering cars, by a condition. You find all cars with RefNumber AAD or AAV.
From your result I conclude, There are Two cars with AAD and no Cars with AAV.

Comment: Everything is fine in your code .Please provide some sample data and output to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to group the results of the query into two arrays, one for AAD and one for AAV? If so, I believe you're looking for the Linq [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results).

Something like:

```
Cars = (from lc in _context.Car.Where(c => mat.Contains(c.RefNumber)) select lc).GroupBy(c => c.RefNumber).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.ToList());
```

That'll return to you a dictionary object, with AAD and AAV as your keys, and the results for each one, in a strongly typed list of Cars. However, if your data doesn't contain any AAV rows, you'll get a dictionary with one key in it, AAD, with the two results.

Comment: Thanks for that. I want the results into one array only

Comment: (from lc in _context.Car.Where(c => mat.Contains(c.RefNumber)) select lc).ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all !

I should have guessed it ! I should have used an IQueryable first !

```
IQueryable<Car> cars = from ld in _context.Car.Where(c => mat.Contains(c.RefNumber))
                                             select new Car
                                             {
                                                 RefNumber = ld.RefNumber
                                            };
            Car [] ExistingCars = cars.ToArray();
```

Comment: How is this any different?